# How to send multiple text field values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm fetching all the values of same field name using jquery

```
$('input[name^="StudentName"]').each(function() {
StudentName+= $(this).val();
alert(StudentName);
});
```

while alert i'm getting all values as one string such as `"Student1Student2Student3"` and so on. how can I separate each name of student ?

```
$.ajax({url:"<?=base_url(); ?>StudentAttendance/SaveAttendance",
data: "StudentName="+StudentName,
success:function(result){
$("#result").html(result);
}});
```

and when i'm sending it through jquery i'm getting only the last field name value as `Student4`. kindly help me out.

**Note: text fields are dynamic**

Comment: Array my friend

Comment: well look at what you are doing! You are just adding them together with no separator.

Comment: First of all in you ajax you want to pass all your StudentName values concatenated? As a literal? You could split them with a comma for example but generally you should use an array for your data as others say.

Comment: You may also send a complete form via AJAX.

Comment: *"i'm getting only the last field name value"* - Where are you "getting" that?  If you're building a longer value in `StudentName` then I would expect that entire value to be sent to the server as a string just like any other value.  While it's clear that perhaps something other than string concatenation would likely be ideal here, what's not clear is what the actual problem is.

Comment: yeah, its array and when i'm not adding it only displays the first record

Comment: @David i wanna send the values of multiple text fields (that are dynamic) to other page..

Comment: try the function as suggested it will work for you

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: @SarmadSoomro: Then what you want is *probably* an array.  Though you can accomplish the same thing with a delimited string that you then parse server-side.  But none of that is really indicated in the problem description in the question.  *In the question* you indicate that somewhere you are seeing only the last value from your collection of values.  That's a different problem entirely, and not one demonstrated within the question.  So overall the actual problem you're facing is unclear.  "I want to do X" doesn't clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

you can split these values with \n.

```
$(this).val().split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions:

- You can give an object in data

  data: { field1: val1, field2: val2 },
- You can concat your fields as a data string

  data: "field1=" + val1 + "&field2=" + val2,

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method of jquery will do it for you

```
 //creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string
 var fields = $( 'input[name^="StudentName"]' ).serializeArray();

  $( "#results" ).empty();
  jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
    $( "#results" ).append( field.value + " " );
  });

   //add div at your html and check 
    <div id="results"> </div>
```